Error Mitigation in Dynamic Quantum Circuits: Alternatives to Dynamical Decoupling?
"I have a regular quantum circuit (i.e., not a dynamic one), let's call it qc. When I run it on a real quantum computer without using dynamical decoupling, the result is poor. However, when I apply dynamical decoupling, the result improves significantly.
Now, I want to convert my circuit into a dynamic one. When I run the dynamic circuit without dynamical decoupling, I again get poor results. However, when I try to run it with dynamical decoupling, I encounter the error: 'Dynamical decoupling currently cannot be used with dynamic circuits.'
How can I fix this? If it's not possible to use dynamical decoupling with dynamic circuits, what other error mitigation or suppression techniques can I apply?"

twirling method don't have any outstanding improvement in neither of circuits

Are you using a particular quantum computing framework (e.g. qiskit, cirq)? The fact that you encounter an error here might indicate a limitation in whatever library you are using.

i am using qiskit v1
